# Searching for HREF links is pulling back incorrect links

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I'm trying to use Excel's VBA to automate the finding and clicking of a certain link. The issue is that this link changes every day (or with every person). The thing is though, that the beginning of the HREF attribute is always the same and it is the only link on that page that has this sort of an HREF.

I'm trying not to make this too complicated, but I want to explain this so you understand my code and why I did what I did: This link opens up a new page, but since it seems difficult to manage multiple browser instances with VBA I decided it would be better to just put code in that would navigate to the link within the same browser and then use objIE.back to loop if need be.

I searched once and the link was the 59th link in the document, so I tried code like:

```
If link59 <> "*ao/party/popuppartyinfo?party*" Then
hrefvalue = line59
'Gets rid of the JavascriptPopup unnecessary text
trimedhrefvalue = Right(link59, 49)
hrefurlvalue = "https://myjobswebsitehere.com" & trimedhrefvalue
objIE.navigate hrefurlvalue
```

The code itself worked, but apparently this link is not always the 59th link in the page depending on the account.

So now I have the following:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to find link..."
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
'objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "execute('RefreshList');"
Set ieLinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Do Until Progress = True
For Each Links In ieLinks
If Links.innerText = "/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId" Then
'Links.Click
Application.StatusBar = "Found link! Please wait"
Links.Value = hrefvalue
trimedhrefvalue = Right(Links, 49)
hrefurlvalue = "https://myjobswebsitehere.com" & trimedhrefvalue
Progress = True
Exit For
End If
Next Links
Loop
```

When this code runs, it always opens a page that has nothing to do with what I searched. In fact, none of the words in "/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId" even show up in the link that it opens incorrectly.

The HTML of the code I am trying to obtain is as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=11111&nav=off')">
```

The whole href stays the same for every single client except for the "partyID" part which changes.

My question is what am I doing wrong here that is getting this search to pull back results that have nothing to do with the innerText I specified?

Comment: If it is at all possible, post the actual URL, not `myjobswebsitehere.com`. That will make it much easier for someone to scan the page and help provide you an answer.

Comment: @FreeMan Unfortunately, the website I'm manipulating is not only secured by username and pass, but also by private VPN so there is no possible way for others to look at the site unless they were sitting at my computer. I can post any relevant HTML code here though and I will change sensitive client information if need be. Anything look obviously wrong with my code to find a specific HREF?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not the expert you need looking at this bit of code, I just posted the comment in hopes you would get a response sooner.

Comment: Just to add to my own post: I figured out one thing I'm doing wrong was using InnerText when I think I should be using outerHTML. Still can't figure it out though

Comment: If you step through the code can you see when it finds the true condition and what it is? Just to make sure the link it's opening is the link it's finding, rather than finding the right one and opening the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:
The innertext of the link was something that changes every single page so for whatever reason that was putting the weird "open the wrong link" hiccup in my code.
Here is the working code:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to find link..."
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
'objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "execute('RefreshList');"
Set ieLinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Do Until Progress = True
For Each Links In ieLinks
If Links.outerHTML Like "<A href=""javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=*" Then
'Links.Click
Application.StatusBar = "Found link! Please wait"
Links.Value = hrefvalue
trimedhrefvalue = Right(Links, 49)
hrefurlvalue = "https://myjobswebsitehere.com" & trimedhrefvalue
objIE.navigate hrefurlvalue
Progress = True
Exit For
End If
Next Links
```